# Word for "under the support/help and protection of"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrases, expressions, vocabulary

*"Homes of a particular community vandalized by the goons under the support and protection of  police."*

How can I say this in a better way? The police was with the goons. Goons got full support and protection from police to carry out riot against a community. 
Homes of a particular community vandalized under/in/with ________ of  police.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105064/discussion-on-question-by-samuraijack-word-for-under-the-support-help-and-prote).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Connivance", which has more pejorative overtones than some other options, is probably your best bet.

OED

> **connivance, n.1. a. The action of conniving; the action of winking at, overlooking or ignoring (an offence, fault, etc.); often implying secret sympathy or approval: tacit permission or sanction; encouragement by forbearing to condemn.**
>
> 1861   "G. Ross W. Bell's Dictionary of the Law of Scotland" (rev. ed.) 297   The husband's connivance in her guilt..is a good defence to the wife against an action of divorce.

"... homes of a particular community vandalized with the connivance of the police."

Comment: This might be another one of those US/British splits, and I did find some support for your usage, but as I have heard and used the word, connivance is always about petty matters. It wouldn't work at this level of wrong doing. Here is the sort of connivance I am familiar with—[was able to sneak out at night with the connivance of a camp counselor](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/connivance). You might connive with your buddy who works at the golf course to let you golf for free in exchange for fixing his car.

Answer (score 2):

"Aegis" I believe is the proper word.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aegis